# Creating a vector out of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 10x10 matrix (called `A`) and I'd like to make a 1x100 vector (called `B`) out of the rows of `A`. And I'm not sure if there is a fast way to program this in MATLAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transpose `A` and read out the elements linearly:

```
At = A.';       %' transpose to read across A
B = At(:).';    %' (:) creates column vector, transpose with .'
```

Short example:

```
>> A=magic(3)
A =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
>> At = A.'; 
>> B = At(:).'
B =
     8     1     6     3     5     7     4     9     2
```